# Function for removing C-style comments from C style string problem

Tags: c, string

I am trying to create a function which removes C-style comments from a string.

I tried using the classic while-loop when using pointers to go through a char array, now by using two pointers(`p2` is a step ahead of `p1`, and they both start at the beginning). I tried checking`*p1 == '/' and when *p2 == '*'`, and when it was true I'd create two new pointers which would find the end of the comment (`*p3 == '*' && *p4 == '/'`), and then I'd create two new pointers `p5` and `p6` , the first of which would point to p1(the first character in the comment, which should be '/', and the second would point to  p4(the last character which would be removed), I'd use a while loop to try and

do `while(*p5++ = *p6++);`

which sadly does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_comments(char* s) {

    char *p1=s;
    char *p2 = s;   
        p2++; // move p2 ahead of p1;


    while(*p1 !='\0' && *p2 !='\0') { 

        if(*p1=='/' && *p2=='*') { // beginning of comment
            char *p3 = p1; // save their positions and
            char *p4 = p2; //create two new pointers

            while(*p3 !='\0' && *p4 !='\0') {
            if(*p3 == '*' && *p4 == '/') { //if end of comment

                    char *p5 = p1;
                    char *p6 = p4;

                    while(*p5++ = *p6++);

                } else p1++;

                p3++;
                p4++;

            }




        }
        p1++;
        p2++;


    }




    }




int main() {


    char arr[] = "This is an /*this is a comment*/ example!";

    remove_comments(arr);

    printf("%s", arr);



    return 0;
}
```

The code above should produce the output `This is an example!`, but the string remains unchanged. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's an ideal time for you to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: This is a common exercise from K&R and there are numerous other examples including ones that stream directly from `getchar()`. This question is essentially caused by a typo and hence not very interesting.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It's also caused by an unneeded increment of `s1`.

Comment: Also please check your compiler diagnostics output - a conforming compiler **must** issue warning for the first mistake. And I suppose you're not using Turbo C 2.0 because that wouldn't work well with Valgrind!

Comment: @JL2210 *and* that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, I know. The first example was obvious even without the warnings. I think online challenges disable compiler warnings, though. I also hate DOS, and I personally would never use it unless it's absolutely required.

Comment: A good strategy for this kind of problem is to draw a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The question is caused by a typo, unneeded increment of ``s1`` and more importantly the fact that I did not know I had to move ``p4`` by one when initializing ``p6``. I would suggest you wait until the problem is resolved so you can have a look at all the errors I produced in order not to mark a question off topic because you think it was produced by a typo and an unneeded increment of s1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn up your compiler warnings (`gcc -Wall`).

This (from a previous revision):

```
test.c: In function ‘remove_comments’:
test.c:11:29: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
         if(*p1 == '/' && p2 == '*')
                             ^~
```

makes one part of the issue really obvious (it can't detect the sequence).

Change this:

```
        if(*p1=='/' && p2=='*') { // beginning of comment
```

to this:

```
        if(*p1=='/' && *p2=='*') { // beginning of comment
```

You're incrementing `s1` when you don't need to, and this causes an error.

Remove this:

```
                else
                    p1++;
```

Along with that, the code here:

```
                if(*p3 == '*' && *p4 == '/')
                { // if end of comment

                    char *p5 = p1;
                    char *p6 = p4;
```

is copying the slash from `p4`.

Change that chunk to this:

```
                if(*p3 == '*' && *p4 == '/')
                { // if end of comment

                    char *p5 = p1;
                    char *p6 = p4+1;
```

and, combined with the other changes, your code works.

I suggest changing `while(*p5++ = *p6++);` to `strcpy(p5, p6);`; `strcpy` may well be faster.

It doesn't produce your exact desired output, but it removes all characters between `/*` and `*/`, inclusive.